# Hide loader on iframe load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I need to hide the loader on iframe load also show when it reload again

```html
<div id="loader" class="holds-the-iframe"><iframe id="frame" src="http://www.test.com" frameborder="0" ></iframe></div>


<style>
.holds-the-iframe {
  background:url(https://i.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.webp) center center no-repeat;
}

</style>
```

What is the best way to solve this? I know It can be made with jquery but I would prefer a pure javascript solution.

Comment: Have you tried with an `onload` function triggered from the iframe?

Comment: `$(document).load(function()`? how to check  specifically for iframe?

Comment: `document.getElementById('frame').onEventListener('load', function(){})` this potentially could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.. I not put image.. I just using word.. You can change it to image.

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="https://www.test.com/" id="foo"></iframe>
<div id="loadingMessage">Loading...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#loadingMessage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #ccc;
    top: 0px;
    left; 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#foo').ready(function () {
    $('#loadingMessage').css('display', 'none');
});
$('#foo').load(function () {
    $('#loadingMessage').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: but why not to use a image?